# Elastic Beanstalk URL root not working - EC2 Elastic IP and Elastic IP Public DNS working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a Django app (1.11.3) to elastic beanstalk (Python 3.4). My issue is that my root route is not working correctly when I use the elastic beanstalk url, but works correctly when using the EC2 Elastic IP or EC2 Elastic IP Public DNS address.

When trying to view the root route of the elastic beanstalk url, the page never loads and ends with chrome showing ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT. All other routes other than the route route (/members, /contact, etc) are working correctly with both the elastic beanstalk url and EC2 IP.

Command used to create elastic beanstalk:

```
eb create examplesitename-staging \
      --branch_default \
      --cname examplesitename-staging \
      --database \
      --database.engine postgres \
      --database.instance db.t2.small \
      --database.size 5 \
      --database.version 9.3.17 \
      --instance_type t2.nano \
      --keyname admin \
      --process \
      --region us-east-1 \
      --single \
      --envvars ENV_VARS_ETC=...
```

Comment: as you say that example.com is NOT working fine but example.com/foo is working fine.. Looks like it's your application issue rather than cloud issue. Try to put a dummy index.html on your root location example.com . This will help you in debugging

Comment: My setup is for elastic beanstalk with a single ec2 instance (no load balancer in between), so elastic beanstalk has a public url example.elasticbeanstalk.com and the ec2 instance it generates has a public url example.ec2.com. I would expect them to show the same thing. The issue is that example.elasticbeanstalk.com does not work, while example.ec2.com does work. Because example.ec2.com works, I believe my app is routing correctly. Note that both example.elasticbeanstalk.com/foo and example.ec2.com/foo work correctly.