# Elastic Beanstalk URL cannot access Website after successful environment update

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I am hosting a Django site on Elastic Beanstalk. I haven't yet linked it to a custom domain and used to access it through the Beanstalk environment domain name like this: http://mysite-dev.eu-central-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/
Today I did some stress tests on the site which led it to spin up several new EC2 instances. Shortly afterwards I deployed a new version to the beanstalk environment via my local command line while 3 instances were still running in parallel. The update failed due to timeout. Once the environment had terminated all but one instance I tried the deployment again. This time it worked. But since then I cannot access the site through the EB environment domain name anymore. I alway get a "took too long to respond" error.
I can access it through my ec2 instance's IP address as well as through my load balancer's DNS. The beanstalk environment is healthy and the logs are not showing any errors. The beanstalk environment's domain is also part of my allowed hosts setting in Django. So my first assumption was that there is something wrong in the security group settings. 
Since the load balancer is getting through it seems that the issue is with the Beanstalk environment's domain. As I understand the beanstalk domain name points to the load balancer which then redirects to the instances? So could it be that the environment update in combination with new instances spinning up has somehow corrupted the connection? If yes, how do I fix this and if no what else could be the cause?
Being a developer and newbie to cloud hosting my understanding is fairly limited in this respect. My issue seems to be similar to this one [Elastic Beanstalk URL root not working - EC2 Elastic IP and Elastic IP Public DNS working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45403980/elastic-beanstalk-url-root-not-working-ec2-elastic-ip-and-elastic-ip-public-dn) 
, but hasn't helped me further 
Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: After one day everything is back to normal. The environment URL works as previously as if the dependencies had recovered overnight.
Obviously a server can experience downtime, but since the site worked fine when accessing the ec2 instance ip and the load balancer dns directly, I am still a bit puzzled about what's going on here.
If anyone has an explanantion for this behaviour, I'd love to hear it.
Otherwise, for those experiencing similar issues after a botched update: Before tearing out your hair in desperation, try just leaving the patient alone overnight and let the AWS ecosystem work its magic.